# Sorting array ignoring special characters in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
Array (
       '9:00',
       '22:00',
       '12:00',
       '*15:00'
)
```

I'm trying to sort as this way:

```
Array (
       '9:00',
       '12:00',
       '*15:00',
       '22:00'
)
```

Is that possible? I'm trying to ignore the asterisk in the array to sort, but the asterisk remains in the element.

Comment: Is the asterisk in front of the 15 a typo? Or is it meant to be there? Are there any other of such characters in the data set?

Comment: If you want to keep asterisk, then you probably need to write your own sorting function. So far, there is no built in function to do that.

Comment: There is no way to sort natively in PHP if you have something like a * preceding. You'll need to make a function to strip leading special chars, use natcasesort (probably the best here) and then reference keys to the original array to get the real value.

Comment: usort() with a callback

Comment: The asterisk always appears in the front of element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$foo = array('9:00', '22:00', '12:00', '*15:00');

usort($foo, function($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace('|[^\d:]|', '', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('|[^\d:]|', '', $b);

    return strnatcmp($a, $b);
});

print_r($foo);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9:00
    [1] => 12:00
    [2] => *15:00
    [3] => 22:00
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically, your strings will have between 4 and 6 characters.  By left padding every string with asterisks to a standard length of 6 characters, you no longer need to perform a natural sort to accommodate missing zeros or asterisks.

Using `array_multisort()` will offer better performance because the data-mutating step will make *n* iterated calls of `sprintf()`, but `usort()` will call `preg_replace()` twice and `strnatcmp()` once *n log n* times (IOW, it's more expensive).

`'*6` means left pad the string (`%s`) with the `*` character to ensure that the string has a length of 6 characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rhJiR))

```
$array = [
       '12:00',
       '*15:00',
       '9:00',
       '22:00'
];

array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => sprintf("%'*6s", $v), $array),
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '9:00',
  1 => '12:00',
  2 => '*15:00',
  3 => '22:00',
)
```

---

Of course this will work just the same too if you don't want to make mapped calls of anything: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1mKO1))

```
array_multisort(
    str_replace('*', '', $array),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```